# check how many times each word from a unique list appears in a dataset

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of unique tokens

```
unique_words
```

and a dataset column that has text

```
dataset['text']
```

I want to count how many times each element of unique_words appears in my entire text data and display k most common of those words.

```
unique_words = ['ab', 'bc', 'cd', 'de']
```

| id | text |
| --- | --- |
| 1x | ab cd de th sk gl wlqm dhwka oqbdm |
| p2 | de de de lm eh nfkie qhas hof |

3 most common words:

```
'de', 100
'ab', 11
'cd', 5
```

Comment: By "dataset" did you mean data **frame**? Pandas/Numpy? What have you tried so far?

Comment: yes pandas dataframe

Comment: what is your output datatype? a series? dictionary? tuple?

Comment: the output doesn't matter, I just need to print it out and see the most common words

Comment: I have used Counter to get all unique words and their counts. I just need a subset of these unique words only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Method 1: Using pandas

This method using vectorized `str` methods to

- split the string into tokens
- expand them and stack them
- use `value_counts()` to get frequency counts
- filter indexes based on `unique_words`
- fetch top k using `.head()` as `value_counts()` already sort counts in descending order

```
import pandas as pd

unique_words = ['ab', 'cd', 'de', 'bc']
counts = dataset['text'].str.split(expand=True).stack().value_counts()
top3 = counts[counts.index.isin(unique_words)].head(3)
top3
```

```
de    4
ab    1
cd    1
dtype: int64
```

---

## Method 2: Using sklearn's CountVectorizer

You can use `CountVectorizer()` from sklearn to get token frequencies for the unique_words by setting them as your vocabulary.

Here is a code example for the sample dataset you have updated in your question.

1. Initialize a `CountVectorizer` with the vocabulary set to `unique_words` using `CountVectorizer(vocabulary=unique_words)`
2. Fit and transform the sentences in the `text` column using this vectorizer, and then convert it into an array, using `cnt.fit_transform(dataset['text']).toarray()`
3. Take the sum of the occurrences of each word in the vocab across the sentences by using `mat.sum(0)`
4. Finally, save it as a series, and use `.nlargest(3)` to get the top k keywords based on the frequency of occurrence across the dataset.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

unique_words = ['ab', 'cd', 'de', 'bc']
cnt = CountVectorizer(vocabulary=unique_words)
mat = cnt.fit_transform(dataset['text'])
tot = mat.sum(0)
top3 = pd.DataFrame(tot.T, index=unique_words)[0].nlargest(3)
top3
```

```
de    4
ab    1
cd    1
dtype: int64
```

Read more about sklearn's CountVectorizer [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html).

---

## Method 3: Using collections.Counter

- First convert the series of sentences to a list using `.tolist()`
- Next, map `str.split` to this iterator to break the sentences into tokens resulting in a list of lists
- Next, use itertools.chain to merge these lists into a chain object
- Then use `Counter` to get word counts in this chain object for all tokens
- Then, you can use a dict comprehension to get only those tokens that are in your `unique_words` list and convert it back to a Counter
- Finally, use `counter.most_common(3)` to get the top k keys based on frequency.

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import chain

counter = Counter(chain.from_iterable(map(str.split, dataset['text'].tolist())))
filtered = Counter({word: counter.get(word,0) for word in unique_words})
top3 = filtered.most_common(3)
top3
```

```
[('de', 4), ('ab', 1), ('cd', 1)]
```

Comment: text is sentences. many tokens per row.

Comment: ah, it wasnt clear. can you please provide a few rows of data as sample input?

Comment: Also are you counting each token multiple times in each row?

Comment: Updated my answer. do check and test the code.

Comment: yes, each time a token is anywhere in that data, I want to count it. majority of these tokens, like 90%, are not from this unique_word list

Comment: ohk, do check my updated answer. this should solve your problem

Comment: this didn't work because the data (600k rows of about 200 tokens each) and the vocabulary list (150k words) is very big

Comment: can you elaborate on what was issue you are seeing when running the code?

Comment: unable to allocate 1.05TiB for an array with shape ...

Comment: hmm makes sense, so the vectorizer is fitting then. let me update my code

Comment: I have used Counter to get all unique words and their counts. I just need a subset of these unique words only.

Comment: do add your code in your question as well and i can fix that to do the subsetting. Meanwhile I have added some fixes to the code to not fail due to memory issues. do check